# Send Flow (Guided Send), Content Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I am trying to send an email to a single contact using content builder. I know it the name has changed to "Send Flow" but I am unsure how to access it, as when I click on the email to send, it only gives me the option to send to an entire data extension/list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are asking how to send it from Content builder, to send it to single contact do the following

1. goto content builder Email
2. click on the email you want to send
3. Click on the edit button -> you will have 3 options
4. select preview and test
5. you will see subscriber preview and attributes
6. click on the folder icon and select the Data extension > select any field > click on select on bottom right corner
7. click on the email icon > Recipients > Individuals - Type the email address of  the single contact you want to send
8. click on send test

Let me know if this was helpful.